# How can i perform date validation in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-validator

I want to write custom validator for validating date given by user as input, Does anyone have idea about writing validator in vuejs2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS Custom Props Validation Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578945/vuejs-custom-props-validation-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use existing Vue.js plugin like Vee Validate (http://vee-validate.logaretm.com) or Vuelidate (https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/).